# Why Does the VS Code Jupyter Extension Keep Timing-out Trying to Find a Kernel That Exists?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, julia, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to set up virtual environments for each language that I use. To do this, I'm running the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10. Within WSL, I'm using Anaconda, installed in `/usr/local/Anaconda`, to create conda virtual environments for each language (i.e. one environment contains all my Python stuff, another contains my R stuff, etc.).

Since WSL doesn't come with a GUI, I'm using Visual Studio Code's (VSCode) Jupyter Notebook Extension to run Jupyter Notebooks to see plots/graphics. So far, I managed to easily create conda environments for Python (with ipython and ipykernel) and R (with IRkernel) and run their code in a notebook via the extension. Each time I set up an environment, the extension is easily able to find the kernel, connect to it and run the code.

However, I've not been able to set up an environment for Julia. I followed the documentation on the Julia website for installing the kernel, which is successfully found by the extension. But, when I try running a cell, the extension says it is trying to connect to the kernel, only for it to timeout and fail.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Create a clean conda environment (`conda create -n Julia && conda activate Julia`)
2. Install the latest version of Julia (`conda install -c conda-forge julia`)
3. Install the latest version of Jupyter (`conda install -c conda-forge jupyter`)
4. Install the Julia kernel with the built-in Julia package manager (`using Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")`)
5. Build the IJulia package (`using Pkg; Pkg.build("IJulia")`)
6. Confirm the presence of the Julia kernel (`jupyter kernelspec list`) which indeed shows the presence of a Julia kernel
7. Reload the VSCode connection to WSL (`Ctrl + Shift + P; >Reload Window`)
8. Shut down WSL via CMD (`wsl --shutdown`) for changes to take effect and reconnect

After I restart VSCode and WSL, the extension shows an option to use the Julia kernel installed in my conda environment: `Julia 1.7.2 (~/.conda/envs/Julia/bin/julia)`. But when I create a cell and run code in a notebook, the extension creates a popup saying that it is connecting to the kernel and after some time an error message shows up:

```
Failed to start the Kernel.
Unable to start Kernel `Julia 1.7.2` due to connection timeout.
View Jupyter log for further details
```

I can also see the kernel spec JSON file in `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/julia-1.7/kernel.json`

```json
{
  "display_name": "Julia 1.7.2",
  "argv": [
    "/home/USER/.conda/envs/Julia/bin/julia",
    "-i",
    "--color=yes",
    "--project=@.",
    "/home/USER/.conda/envs/Julia/share/julia/packages/IJulia/AQu2H/src/kernel.jl",
    "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "language": "julia",
  "env": {},
  "interrupt_mode": "signal"
}
```

The log file starts showing problems here:

```
info 17:50:48.378: Process Execution: cwd: ~
cwd: ~
warn 17:50:48.893: StdErr from Kernel Process [91m[1mERROR: [22m[39m
warn 17:50:49.138: StdErr from Kernel Process LoadError: 
warn 17:50:49.795: StdErr from Kernel Process ArgumentError: Package IJulia not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")` to install the IJulia package.
```

The extension says it cannot find the IJulia kernel. This perplexes me because I can see the kernel spec in my home directory, the jupyter binary I installed from conda says that its there and the Jupyter Notebook extension can see the kernel. I have no explanation as to why the extension can see the kernel, match up the kernelspec but not be able to connect to it. Help would greatly be appreciated!